# Power Query M. Json array of key-pair transform in Column

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

Thanks for your help,

I'm trying to transform the Array called 'Tags' hosting a list of pair of key-values into a list of columns: CustomerId, CustomerDisplayName, CustomerPath where each list contains a respective value being a store for each charge.

```
{
    "periodFrom": "2020-11-09T00:00:00",
    "periodTo": "2020-12-08T00:00:00",
    "charges": [
        {
            "listPrice": 5.05,
            "netPrice": 5.05,
            "netPriceProrated": 5.05,
            "subTotal": 5.05,
            "currency": "CAD",
            "isBilled": true,
            "isProratable": true,
            "deductions": [],
            "fees": [],
            "invoice": {
                "number": "2822835",
                "date": "2020-11-16T00:00:00",
                "periodFrom": "2020-10-09T00:00:00",
                "periodTo": "2020-11-08T00:00:00"
            },
            "taxes": [
                {
                    "name": "GST",
                    "appliedRate": 5.0
                },
                {
                    "name": "QST",
                    "appliedRate": 9.975
                }
            ],
            "tags": [
                {
                    "name": "CustomerId",
                    "value": "42c8edf4-365a-4068-bde6-33675832afbb"
                },
                {
                    "name": "CustomerDisplayName",
                    "value": "Blue Sky Group"
                },
                {
                    "name": "CustomerPath",
                    "value": "Devmesh Co-Branded/Blue Sky Group"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

}

[image]

Here the actual snippet of code I'm actually

```
let
    ...
    Response2 = Table.FromRecords( { Response } ),
    #"Expand1" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Response2, "charges"),
    #"Expand2" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expand1", "charges", {"productId", "productName", "sku", "chargeId", "chargeName", "chargeType", "periodFrom", "periodTo", "quantity", "listPrice", "netPrice", "netPriceProrated", "subTotal", "currency", "isBilled", "isProratable", "deductions", "fees", "invoice", "taxes", "tags"}, {"charges.productId", "charges.productName", "charges.sku", "charges.chargeId", "charges.chargeName", "charges.chargeType", "charges.periodFrom", "charges.periodTo", "charges.quantity", "charges.listPrice", "charges.netPrice", "charges.netPriceProrated", "charges.subTotal", "charges.currency", "charges.isBilled", "charges.isProratable", "charges.deductions", "charges.fees", "charges.invoice", "charges.taxes", "charges.tags"})
in
    #"Expand2"
```

Comment: For clarity, can you show exactly what you want your end result to be for this example?

Comment: @AlexisOlson I just add a screen capture made with Excel Thanks for your help.